# Rxjava not returning data

Tags: android, rx-java

I need to handle the boot complete intent in android and then I need to make 4 network calls to get data and then need to compare the each item and send the notifications if it meets.

I tried to write this code but it is not working.

```
subscription = provider
            .getAllItems()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<ContentValues>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscription.unsubscribe();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<ContentValues> list) {
                    for(ContentValues contentValues : list) {
                        Long currentTime  = (Long)contentValues.get(EquakeContract.EarthQuakeEntry.TIME);
                        Double mag = (Double) contentValues.get(EquakeContract.EarthQuakeEntry.MAGNITIUTE);
                        if(currentTime >time && mag > Double.parseDouble(minMagnitude)) {
                            sendNotification(contentValues);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

It is calling to this function

```
    public Observable<List<ContentValues>> getAllItems() {
    return api.getEquakeItems();
}
```

it is calling to this function

```
    public Observable<List<ContentValues>> getEquakeItems() {

    return getCategoryList()
            .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<String>, List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public List<String> call(final List<String> dataSnapshot) {
                    return dataSnapshot;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<EarthQuake>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<EarthQuake> call(final String categoryId) {
                    return equakeService.getEarthQuakeItems(categoryId);
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<EarthQuake, List<ContentValues>>() {
                @Override
                public List<ContentValues> call(final EarthQuake earthQuake) {
                    String[] data = earthQuake.getMetadata().getUrl().split("/");
                    String categoryId = data[data.length-1].split(".")[0];
                    Log.e("CategoryId",categoryId);
                    return mapItems(earthQuake,categoryId);
                }
            });
}
```

I am not getting the data as return statement is not executed. I don't know what mistake I am doing here.

I need List data in first function.

I am new to rxjava so any help will be appreciated.

**I am running this in intent service as I need to parse the list of contentvalues and send the notifications**

I am getting arrayindexoutofbound exception but don't know where?

I am getting the observable list like below

```
    public Observable<List<String>> getCategoryList() {
    return Observable.from(Arrays.asList(EarthQuakeConstants.SIGNIFICANT_CATEGORY,EarthQuakeConstants.ONE_END_CATEGORY,EarthQuakeConstants.TWO_FIVE_CATEGORY,EarthQuakeConstants.ALL_END_CATEGORY,EarthQuakeConstants.FOUR_FIVE_CATEGORY)).toList();
}
```

and making 1 network call on each item return by this.

Comment: One mistake is that you ignore any errors by having an empty `onError`. You are likely having a NullPointerException or an index out-of-bounds exception somewhere.

Comment: It always show the exact line that exception occurred in the LogCat, check the line cause arrayindexoutofbound exception